# how to add list in `DATAGRIDVIEW` with combobox on runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

i tried the following code but it adds the list every time when we start new row so if we have two rows its add it two times if we move to three rows it adds the list for three time

Please provide me simple and easy way to add the list into the combobox of datagridview

```
    Dim CON As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; username=root; password=Masoom1; database=airtech_db;")
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * from `Suppliers`;", CON)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from `Suppliers`;", CON)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim TOTAL_SUPPLIERS As Integer



    CON.Open()
    da.Fill(ds)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    TOTAL_SUPPLIERS = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
    Dim TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS) As String, ARRAYINDEX As Integer
    ARRAYINDEX = 0
    Do While dr.Read() = True
        TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(ARRAYINDEX) = dr("Supplier_Name").ToString()
        ARRAYINDEX += 1
    Loop
    CON.Close()


    Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    For k = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        cbCell = DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("Supplier_Name")
        For iIndex = 0 To UBound(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY) - 1
            cbCell.Items.Add(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(iIndex))
        Next

    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it only once for a column.

For example you can populate combobox when loading a form.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyForm.Load
    With Me.DataGridView.Columns("Supplier_Name")
       .DataSource = GetSupplierNames()
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetSupplierNames() As List(Of String)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Supplier_Name FROM Suppliers"

    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using command As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
            connection.Open()
            Dim supplierNames = new List(Of String)()

            Using reader AS MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim name As String = reader.GetString(0)
                    supplierNames.Add(name)
                End While
            End Using

            Return supplierNames
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

well I found a simple solution to existing code to fix the problem as every time it runs clear the existing list and let the list add again so add `cbCell.Items.Clear()`to code helped

```
 Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    For k = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        cbCell = DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("Supplier_Name")
        cbCell.Items.Clear()

        For iIndex = 0 To UBound(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY)
            cbCell.Items.Add(TOTAL_SUPPLIERS_ARRAY(iIndex))
        Next
    Next
```